# Crystal Reports 2011: Filter on maximum number per group

Tags: filter, crystal-reports, formula

I am new to Crystal Reports and I have the following question:

In one of my fields I have the following type of records

```
AIF145361

AIF145361/1

AIQ023078

AIQ023078/1

...
```

Now I want only the records without the "/1"

How do I begin?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kwinten

Comment: are these records in database? or in crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter

- in the query (`WHERE SOMEFIELD NOT LIKE '%/1'`)
- in report data Report\Selection Formula\Record ( drag-drop the field and type `'contains "/1"'`)
- in report presentation: Section Expert\Details\Suppress (use the same formula of line above).

Comment: Which one did you choose? If it is, mark the problem as solved.